# текст не исчезает при наведении

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

текст не исчезает при наведении, на картинке текст, навожу на неё срабатывает hover но текст который был сразу не исчезает 
использовал: overflow: hidden; display: none; opacity: 0; font-size: -999px;

```
<div class="personal__coach services__item_main">
               <div class="services__item_text">
                   Личный тренер
               </div>
               <div class="services__item_additionally ">
                   <div class="services__item_hover">
                       Личный тренер
                   </div>
                   <p class="price">
                       235 рн
                   </p>
                   <p class="description">
                       Excepteur sint cupidatat nonsunt  proident, sunt culpa deserunt officia mollit anim est ideaes cupidatat laborum.
                   </p>
                   <button href="#" class="recording  recording__btn">
                       Подробнее
                   </button>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: желательно и стили показать?

Comment: Первый раз задаю, вопрос. Извиняюсь что не весь код скинул. Вот ссылка на сайт http://www.test-project.ho.ua

Answer (score 1):

Решение на jQuery

P.S. Хотя бы css блока с классом "services_item" скинули

```
let servicesBlocks = $('.services_item');

servicesBlocks.children().on('hover', function() {
    $(this).children('.services__item_text').css('display', 'none');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.services__item_text').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.services__item_additionally {
    width: 292px;
    height: 488px;
    margin-top: -249px;
    background: #d94b1dd6;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но а как полностью убрать текст?